# Java-Error: getWriter() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to add a tomcat filter, however upon execution, I receive the error message that getWriter() has already been called for this response.

The code in question:

package filters;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public final class ExampleFilter implements Filter {
```

[...]

```
public class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private CharArrayWriter output;

    public String toString() {
        return output.toString();
    }

    public CharResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        output = new CharArrayWriter();
    }

    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return new PrintWriter(output);
    }
}
```

[..]

How can I prevent this error?